# Looking for a projectile motion experiment tool

Tags: soft-question, projectile

Is there a name for the device used in physics experiments when one wants to show that (under certain conditions) if two balls are initially at the same height and one is dropped while the other is fired horizontally then they land at the same time? 
I recall a physics professor using a device which held two marbles. The device shoots one of the marbles and drops the other.

Comment: At our university, there is a crossbow that aims at a stuffed teletubby toy. When the arrow is shot, the teletubby is dropped. It will still hit it, just lower. That might be even more entertaining.

Comment: The experiment is called _The Monkey and the Hunter_ or _Shoot the Monkey._ See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Monkey_and_the_Hunter) Wikipedia page and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0jGZnMf3rPo) Youtube video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some equipment available online if you'd like to purchase such a device.

http://www.vernier.com/products/accessories/iom-vpl/
http://www.sciencelabsupplies.com/Newtons_2nd_Second_Law_of_Motion.html

Comment: You can also find one here: http://www.sciencelabsupplies.com/Newtons_2nd_Second_Law_of_Motion.html